# Hibernate - can I mix named and positional parameters?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a queryString along the lines of:

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT C.FIRSTNAME AS firstName, C.LASTNAME as lastName FROM ADDRESSBOOK_CONTACT AS C WHERE C.ADDRESSBOOK_ID = :addressbookId AND firstName = ?");
```

When setting my positional parameter, the query is run as normal but there is no result:

```
query.setParameter(0, "firstname1010");
query.setParameter("addressbookId", addressbook.getId());
```

Which is wrong.  If I change my positional to named:

```
query.setParameter(firstname, "firstname1010");
```

Then my query returns the correct results.

Without going into a convoluted explanation as to why I am doing this, I would like to know if mixing the two types should be supported or not?  I am using hibernate 3.6.3.Final

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Class level docs on `org.hibernate.Query`:

> You may not mix and match JDBC-style parameters and named parameters
>   in the same query.

So the behaviour you're seeing is completely expected.